# Explain execution flow of following complex javascript return statement

Tags: javascript

I've found very hard to follow the execution flow of this return statement. If anyone could explain how its execution flows work and even better if you can explain whats the pros and cons of creating such complex statements rather a more readable multi-line statement I would greatly appretiate.

```
return option = option ? option : {}, typeof option.xValue == "boolean" && (_ready = option.xValue), option.name && _ready == !1 && log(option.name + "(" + option.caller + " )  API not ready.", "E"), _ready
```

Comment: Obvious con: it's confusing.

Comment: There's no pro unless you want to be sure nobody wants to take your job and then maintain your program. Seriously, this is malpractice.

Comment: If you really need to make it one statement (dunno why, maybe your editor breaks when you hit 10 statements in a function?) then at least spread it on a few indented lines to make it readable.

Comment: I would like read other statements, because I don't understand the scope of other statements after first comma

Comment: Reading about [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) might help.

Comment: Read about the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) (and what Teemu linked to). It boils down to `return _ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression uses the comma operator to do multiple statements, and the short-circuit operation of the `&&` operator as an `if` expression.

You can write the code as:

```
if (!option) {
  option = {};
}
if (typeof option.xValue == "boolean") {
  _ready = option.xValue;
}
if (option.name && _ready == false) {
  log(option.name + "(" + option.caller + " )  API not ready.", "E")
}
return _ready;
```

The only advantage of writing it as single complex expression is that it is a single complex expression. The reason for wanting that might be to make the code harder to read, or perhaps that it is slightly shorter.

Comment: Thanks, so whats the short-circuit for || operator. Somewhere else I found this:
me.myfunc(caller) || (txt = ' "caller" argumant is not alphanumeric.', isOK = !1)

Comment: The `||` operator evaluates the first operand, and if that is falsy, it evaluates the second operand. You could write that as `if (!me.myfunc(caller)) { txt = ' "caller" argumant is not alphanumeric.'; isOK = false; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to determine how all the operators in the expression should be grouped:

```
return 
    option = 
        option ? option : {},
    typeof option.xValue == "boolean" &&
        (_ready = option.xValue), 
    option.name && 
        _ready == !1 && 
            log(option.name + "(" + option.caller + " )  API not ready.", "E"), 
    _ready
```

The comma operator that separates each of the parameters evaluates each expression and returns the rightmost one. So first it performs the `option` assignment. Then it evaluates each of the `&&` expressions, which might assign to `_ready` or call `log()`. Then it finally returns the value of `_ready`.

I don't think he actually needed the parentheses around the `_ready` assignment, he threw us a bone there.

There's no practical reason for writing such a complex statement. People who do this are just trying to show how clever they are, IMHO. See Guffa's answer for a rewrite into understandable code.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Can you also explain what || does in such a statement. 
for instance this:
`code` typeof option.xValue == "boolean" ||
        (_ready = option.xValue), `code`

Comment: The `||` operator evaluates its arguments from left to right, returning the first truthy value. So if `option.xValue` is a boolean, it will return `true` and not execute the `_ready` assignment. If it's not boolean, it will execute the assignment.